# How to install LUbuntu 19.10 on an Atomic Pi?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu

The Atomic Pi is a surplus x86 based SBC, and comes with LUbuntu pre-installed.  However, on mine, the audio didn't work until I ran LUbuntu 19.19 via a LiveUSB.  Now I want to install it.

I'm used to have to choose "try" or "install" in the boot menu, but I don't see that, it just boots to the desktop.  On the desktop, there's an "install Lubuntu" icon, which starts a wizard, which is very promising.

However, a few steps in, there's an option to configure partitions.  In various OS installers, I usually see an "automatic" option somewhere where it takes over the whole disk and sets it up the way it wants.  There is only a manual option.  I can mark the partitions on the eMMC for deletion, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do next.

The documentation I am able to find ([LUbuntu docs](https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_installation), [Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu), [random search result](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-lubuntu-linux-distribution-pc-bootable-usb-drive.html)) doesn't mention this wizard at all, so I'm not sure how to proceed to give it what it wants to install.

Is there an automatic install option?  If not, how should I use this wizard to set up LUbuntu?

I'm using "lubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso", which I used Rufus 3.8p to image it to a USB stick.

Comment: Ubuntu flavors are *yy.mm* in format; there is no 19th month in our calendar.  Lubuntu docs are are at lubuntu.me, manual at manual.lubuntu.me etc. Did you verify your downloaded ISO? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and write to media ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  Have you tried using the manual?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

Try going from the Ubuntu 19.10 vanilla server image, then installing via apt. Atomic pi has an intel chip so it will take the original amd64 image:

1. Install from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/server

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get lubuntu-desktop
```

(On my atomic pi I use a super minimal install via the same process but using `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop` )

You can do the same thing for raspberry pi's just using the raspberry pi server armhf ubuntu 19.10 image rather than the amd64.

Comment: OP, did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: It will work, you need to follow the steps to install ubuntu-server from an SD card. Then boot the atomic pi while holding "DEL" and choose to boot into the SD card from the boot options.